# Error after update PHP to 7.3 with reference to the code

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

After update to PHP version above 7.1, I've got an error:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant slug - assumed 'slug' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

The indication applies to the code that I use to support languages on the page (Polyang plugin).

Part of code:

```
global $current_lang;
$current_lang = pll_current_language(slug);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: If there is a solution to update packages/libraries - then I can re-open the question.

Comment: It's OP's code -and not a library/package- that's at fault, it seems. If so, they should be able to fix it themselves by following the instructions from the suggested link.

Comment: The solution is to add ' ', so in this example it will be `('slug')`